# Service Fabric long-term callbacks

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to figure out the best pattern for developing a service which can maintain some sort of long-term callback strategy. For instance, let's say I have a service `DoLongThingService`. When you call `.Begin`on this service, it schedules for execution some long process. When the process is finished, I need it to wake up the first service. Basically long term workflow-type stuff.

This actually sort of works fine with actors. Since I can pass an `ActorReference` to the `DoLongThingService.Begin` method, and that service can `Bind` that actor, and invoke a method on it to signal completion.

But what about when I'm not using Actors? How can I pass a reference to one service to another? The first service is going to be Stateful, so it can keep track of it's outstanding requests. But, there might be multiple instances of that Stateful service floating around. So how do I get the response back to the right one?

Answer (score 0):

The service URI and partition key can uniquely identify partition of a service in the system. You can use this to resolve the service address using ServicePartitionResolver or if your service implements IService, you can use this information to create ServiceProxy like ActorProxy and make method calls back to the service.

Comment: How about doing this in a situation where the service that is invoking the callback does not have access to the IActor interface type of it's caller? It's just a service that can handle requests from any sort of clients, and does not need to explicitly know what they are, nor can it, except that they support a single type of callback.

I am trying to device an API that looks something like this:

ServiceProxy.Create<IService>().Begin(this.GetCallback(MethodName))

Essentially, invoke the service, and when it is finished, have it invoke this particular method name of the caller.

Comment: wasabi - I'm facing the same problem, did you find anything useful?